# What is the best way to control for within-group heterogeneity?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, panel-data, heteroscedasticity, biostatistics

I have panel data with repeated measurements from households. There's likely heterogeneity within panels that I need to account for. I'm planning on using a Poisson regression, but I am not sure the best way to control for heterogeneity.

Comment: How about specifying a covariance structure to account for heterogeneity of residuals; probably by specifying some `weights` when using `lme`? Not to send you in a wild-goose chase though: Have you used the "homoskedastic" version of your Mix.Eff. model and you saw heteroskedasticity in the residuals it gives? (Also you could probably transform your response variable but it wouldn't be my first pick...)